# AES_ctr128_encrypt on Solaris doesnt decrypt same as other OS's

Tags: openssl, aes, endianness, encryption-symmetric

I've compiled the libcrypto.so shared library from openssl-1.0.1g for various platforms. Using the shared library, my app is able to encrypt/decrypt data between any of the following:

- Linux i386
- Linux x86_64
- Linux PPC
- AIX RISC

These can decrypt their own data, but NOT each other, nor any of the above:

- Solaris i386
- Solaris SPARC

I first thought this was an endian issue, butAIX/RISC and Linux/PPC are BE, and they seem to play well wit the Linux i386 and x86_64 (LE).

The Solaris systems are:

```
SunOS pluto 5.9 Generic_Virtual sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120
SunOS nemo 5.9 Generic_118559-11 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

The libcrypto.so was compiled with:

```
#[openssl-1.0.1g] ./Configure solaris-sparcv9-cc shared 
#[openssl-1.0.1g] ./Configure solaris-x86-cc shared
```

NOTE that the Solaris systems both use "/opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc" as the compiler, and all others use "gcc".

I have verified that I am always starting with the same IV/counter and symkey when encrypting and decrypting. The encryption routines are well embededed in my programs, but this is basically all that I'm doing:

```
uchar ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE], ecount[AES_BLOCK_SIZE], symkey[16];
uint num = 0, bits = 128;
uchar *buf, *ebuf; /* these are malloc'd and buf set to data to encrypt/decrypt */
...
memcpy(symkey, MYTESTKEY, 16);
memset(ecount, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
memset(ivec, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
memcpy(ivec, SOMEDATA, 8); /* from RAND_seed() and RAND_bytes() */
AES_set_encrypt_key(symkey, bits, &outkey);
...
AES_ctr128_encrypt(inp, outp, bytes, key, ivec, ecount, &num);
```

Again, this always works when encrypting/decrypting on the same system, only decodes to junk when one of the systems is Solaris. I'm using very old Solaris OS and boxes, however, since I have to maintain backward compatibility.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `MYTESTKEY`? Is it 16 bytes? Does a `memset(symkey, 0x00, sizeof(symkey))` before the `strcpy(symkey, MYTESTKEY)` help the situation?

Comment: Yes, this is just simple example of the code I'm using. MYTESTKEY and SOMEDATA could be anything, but are always the same for both encryption and decryption. And, sorry in my haste to provide a simple example, I used strcpy when I meant to use memcpy, so I edited the above question.

Comment: Well, I thought about it a little last night. CTR is essentially a stream mode. So are you seeing a match for the first *N* cipher characters among platforms, or are they completely different? Can you duplicate if you use a NULL key and NULL nonce (that is a string of 0x00)?

Comment: Well, I always start with a random IV in the highest 8-bytes as in my example, but using the same key. I verified that the same key and IV were being used on the client side for the decryption. But since the IV differed each time, the garbage output also differed. I might have expected the first block to decrypt properly if it had to do with the counter, then get garbage after, but I get garbage for the entire message.

So, I set both the key and the IV to nulls, and I still get garbage (again only between solaris and anything else), but at least the garbage comes up the same every time.

Comment: The last thing I can help you with is to ask if `solaris-sparcv9-cc` included `-DB_ENDIAN` during compile; and if `solaris-x86-cc` included `-DL_ENDIAN` during compile. Otherwise, I think Andy or Dr. Henson (or perhaps other OpenSSL devs) should be engaged. I'd start by asking on [openssl-users](https://www.openssl.org/support/community.html), and then [openssl-dev](https://www.openssl.org/support/community.html) if there are no takers on openssl-users.

Comment: With CTR mode, if the IV is different, you *should* expect the entire message to be garbled. The IV is actually a nonce, the starting value of the counter. CTR differs from CBC in that aspect.

Comment: @jww: Yes, the -D[BL]_ENDIAN is correct, and the issue does not occur between systems of different endianness.

Comment: @owlstead: I used the same IV and key for both encryption and decryption. I tested it using an empty IV just to see if the "garbage" decrypted data came out the same each time, and it did (even between Solaris/aix/Linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update, I converted to EVP but no difference. I recompiled libcrypto.so with GCC also with no difference (using solaris64-sparcv9-gcc) - until I removed the link to cc from /usr/bin. Then I recompiled using GCC again and this time it worked. I didn't have time to investigate further, but it implies that some of the objects were still being compiled with cc, even after specifying *-gcc. Unfortunately there's no GCC available for our old Solaris-x86 V9 system, so we won't be supporting V9 on intel anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the higher end OpenSSL [EVP](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html#) functionality.

Check for instance [this message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/XjN1cyEJIaQ) by one of the core devs:

> There is no guarantee that the low level cipher context (or indeed any similar
>   context) will be the same across platforms. Endian differences, padding and
>   platform specific optimisations can result in different data at the machine
>   level. The results of using contexts on the appropriate platform should
>   obviously be consistent though.

Comment: That was a good find owlstead. Its sad that that's the position they are taking for functions that are part of a public interface. For completeness, the FIPS User Guide does not state that restriction (of using `EVP_*` functions). It makes me wonder what's broke where, and why its only mentioned on the developers mailing list....

Comment: When we wrote this CTR wasn't enabled in EVP, and we used the many accepted examples of AES_ctr128_encrypt(). Solaris was added later but I can't say if we ever had need to test between Solaris and others until now (we've always tested between AIX and Linux). It won't be easy to make changes to our code at that level, since we we were just wanting to update to the newest crypto library since our SSL version contained the heartbleed bug (tho we don't use the heartbeat function). Maybe I'll start by finding a GCC that'll run on these old SunOS boxes to see if that works.

Comment: Ah, just read the code in the message you referred to. Perhaps this isn't a CTR issue at all, but the AES_set_encrypt_key(). If that's the case, I would have expected this to problem to be more wide-spread, especially since that comment was from 2012.

Comment: True but if the EVP function runs then the functionality is probably as intended. Don't get me started on documentation or code quality of OpenSSL.  That was an issue way before heartbleed and probably one of the causes.